# Bootstrap how to spread elements around the edges of the screen

Tags: bootstrap-5

I took an example header from the Bootstrap-5 library.

```html
<header class="p-3 mb-3 border-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center">

      <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

      <ul class="nav col-8 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-left mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-secondary">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">About</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="col-md-3 text-end justify-content-end">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2">Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign-up</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

How do I make the menu button, along with the rest of the menu items, be located on the left edge from the very beginning.
And the Login and Sign-up buttons were located at the very end on the right edge.

tried to add justify-content-... has no effect

I need something like this
[image]

Comment: can you share the expected result on a picture?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `container-fluid` instead of `container`. That should give you a regular container but it's edges will be pretty much the width of any screen it is shown on.

```
<header class="p-3 mb-3 border-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
```